# Error after sorting libraries

Tags: java, web-applications, war

I had a big JSF project which I tried to remove few libraries, I assumed unuseful. After doing some other changes with that, I get this error.

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
```

I restored the libraries, still the same error keeps coming. I went through the full stack trace, still I get the same error. I tried it in another computer to get the same error. Can any one, please help.

I use netbeans 7.3 for the development. I use JSF 2.1, Primefaces, JPA with EclipseLink and GlassFish 3.1.

Full stack trace is below.

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context ''
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:672)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:670)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:865)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:656)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaValidatorComponentManager.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.AbstractXMLSchema.newValidatorHandler(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getBuilderForSchema(ConfigManager.java:1130)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:999)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:911)
    ... 48 more

SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context  failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5571)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5384)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:672)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:670)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:865)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:656)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaValidatorComponentManager.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.AbstractXMLSchema.newValidatorHandler(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getBuilderForSchema(ConfigManager.java:1130)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:999)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:911)
    ... 48 more

WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
INFO: file:/E:/sc/healthoffice/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_HOPU logout successful
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with the xerces lib. https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11638

Comment: Try to do a clean build of your project

Comment: Rebuild it. Restart the server. Tried in in another machine. Still No response.